# SEO: Domain name with dash or binded together

Tags: seo, analytics, technical-seo

As I have made some research on different "SEO" [websites](https://moz.com/learn/seo/domain) and [blogs](https://www.website.com/website-builder-and-web-design/how-to-choose-a-seo-friendly-domain-name), everyone recommends NOT using dash/hyphen in their domain names for readability and not looking *spammy*. I did not found any real data on if only one hyphen/dash is SEO harmful or not.

Question:
For a simple and easy to remember domain. Example:
*sports wear* should use `sports-wear.com` or `sportswear.com`

In my opinion, the dash version is easier to read and possible harder to remember but what about SEO?
**One single dash** helps the keyword "sports wear" or make it difficult to match the domain for the web crawlers?

Anyone had experienced / tested this fact?

Answer (score 1):

Domain name is not a ranking factor. There is no direct advantage or disadvantage in using a domain with or without hyphens. But when it comes to SEO, you may have to think about how a user perceives a domain. For years now, we all have seen several spammy domains with hyphens in them. Hence, a user who takes a second or two to choose from top-ranked pages may skip visiting a domain with hyphens in the name. This may indirectly hurt SEO by reducing the number of eyeballs and backlinks in the long run. However, I would recommend surveying a handful of your potential audience on how they perceive a domain name with or without hyphens.